# Checking multiple checkboxes at same time causes $apply already in progress error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When a user clicks on a button to select all checkboxes in a single table, I use this code.

```
$("#workOneTable .rsvLine input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
        this.click();
    }
});
```

When the code runs I get the $apply already in progress error, and I am not calling $apply at all.
I have to perform the click on each checkbox in the table selected too add each row that the checkbox is in to a list array. If I wrap this code in a $timeout I do not get the errors but my checkboxes will not get checked either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT

This is the working code.

```
if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
 var a = $(this);
 setTimeout(function() {
     a.click();
 })
}
```

Comment: Don't mixed up jquery & angular code together. If you're using angular, you can wrap input type='checkbox' in ng-repeat and using ng-change / ng-checked to perform some other action..

Comment: @digit, I am building my page with angular and reactjs. In a separate modal window the user has the option to select all checkboxes with a specific class name in a specific table. That is where I am using the jquery to select those checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event is running digest cycle which is conflicting with current digest cycle. you can use `setTimeout()`

can you change this

```
if ( !$( this ).prop( "checked" ) )
{
    this.click();
}
```

into

```
if ( !$( this ).prop( "checked" ) )
{
    var a = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){a.click();})
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I am also using Typescript as well. I am injecting ng.ITimeoutService into my ts page and I get the error that this.$timeout is not a function. if I change and use setTimeout then I get an error on this.click is not a function

Comment: use setTimeout and $("#yourElement").click()

Comment: This is what I have now and nothing happens when it is called.
$( "#workOneTable .rsvLine input[type=checkbox]" ).each( function ()
                {
                    if ( !$( this ).prop( "checked" ) )
                    {
                        setTimeout( function () { $('.rsvLine').click(); } )
                    }
                } );

Comment: what about first error $apply in progress error? has it romoved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146199/discussion-between-hasan-and-ayordy67).